# binding ajax response to vue.js (multiple requests on single page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, vue.js

After a few days researching Vue.js and how it can interact with laravel i have come to a grinding holt and i am starting to wonder two things: One is im just not good enough with my knowledge to continue with my desire to enhance our user experience or two: its not possible to do what i am trying to do so hopefully someone with greater knowledge can help me overcome my road block.

Please forgive my rather basic mock-up!

[image: My very basic mock example of how the request currently works!]

Everything works fine as far as jquery / Ajax is concerned however i have tried to move over to vue.js and that's when things are not running to smoothly.

I have the Ajax request working fine however when ever i use this.$set or this.$http for the get or post request i get this message:

```
11:14:28.690 TypeError: this.$http is undefined 1 vue:61:21
    window.onload/queryAPI http://me.dev/vue:61:21
    window.onload/ajaxVm<.methods.callAjax http://me.dev/vue:55:29
    n http://me.dev/newjs/vue.js:6:836
    G/< http://me.dev/newjs/vue.js:6:6272

11:24:21.000 TypeError: this.$set is not a function 1 vue:34:29
    window.onload/queryAPI/<.success http://me.dev/vue:34:29
    jQuery.Callbacks/fire http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js:3305:11
    jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js:3435:7
    done http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js:9242:5
    .send/callback/< http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js:9484:9
```

My full testing document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/newjs/vue.js"></script>

    <title>VueJS</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
            var ajaxVm = new Vue({
                el:'#test',
                data:{
                    User:{
                        Name: 'John Doe'
                    },
                    datas: 'Hi'
                },
                methods:{
                    callAjax: function(e){
                        queryAPI();
                    }
                }
            });

            var queryAPI = function(){
                this.$http.post('/vue/ajax', this.formData).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function() {
                    console.log('failed');
                })
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <label id="data">@{{datas}}</label>
    <label>@{{User.Name}}</label>
    <br/>
    <button v-on:click="callAjax">
        Call Ajax
    </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And with ajax/jquery as apose to this.$http it works fine apart from this.$set as i have to revert to using jquery to update the element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/newjs/vue.js"></script>
        <title>VueJS</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
            window.onload=function(){
                var ajaxVm = new Vue({
                    el:'#test',
                    data:{
                        User:{
                            Name: 'John Doe'
                        },
                        datas: 'Hi'
                    },
                    methods:{
                        callAjax: function(e){
                            queryAPI();
                        }
                    }
                });

                var queryAPI = function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/vue/ajax',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data:  ajaxVm.$data ,
                        success:function(data){
                            $('#data').html(data.Message);
                            console.log(data);
                            //this.$set('datas', data.Name)
                        },
                        error:function(xhr,text,exception){
                            console.error(exception);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <label id="data">@{{datas}}</label>
    <label>@{{User.Name}}</label>
    <br/>
    <button v-on:click="callAjax">
        Call Ajax
    </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have both vue.js 2.0.5 and vue-resource 1.0.3 included and I have tried using npm with gulp to a single .js file and I've also tried to include them individually via cdn and no matter how I do it I still get the errors when using this.$http or this.$set, I'm starting to wonder if its vue-resource related? IS there any other way I can bind my ajax call to an element or component, I have no clue what so ever what I can not get the thing working as should, Everything seems to be put together correctly and I have read through endless other vuejs related questions but everything is limiting when your knowledge is somewhat little.

Thanks, I will be extremely grateful for any advice on this as its driving me insane!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a scope issue. When using `this.$http` `this` must refer to the Vue instance, You cannot call `$set` or `$http` with `this` outside of the Vue instance, so you need to place your ajax request inside the view model:

```
var ajaxVm = new Vue({
    el:'#test',
    data:{
        User:{
            Name: 'John Doe'
        },
        datas: 'Hi'
    },
    methods:{
        callAjax: function(e){
           // Now this refers to the Vue instance
           this.$http.post('my-url',this.data).then((response) => {
                // Response logic here
           })
        }
    }
});
```

When you do the following, `this` refers to the enclosing function:

```
var queryAPI = function(){
  //here this refers to queryAPI, not vue
}
```

To call `$http` from outside the view model you need to reference the Vue instance directly:

```
var queryAPI = function(){
                // Now we are calling $http from the "ajaxVm" vue model instance
                ajaxVm.$http.post('/vue/ajax', this.formData).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function() {
                    console.log('failed');
                })
            }
```

Also remember that anything wrapped inside a function creates it's own reference to `this` unless you use an arrow function (these exmaples assume that you have placed you code inside a Vue instance):

```
this.$http.get('/foo').this(function(response){
      // here this only refers to the function, not the Vue instance
});
```

With an arrow function found in ECMA6:

```
this.$http.get('/foo').this((response) =>{
      // Because we used an arrow function, no new context is created
      // so this refers to the Vue instance
});
```

Comment: Excellent indepth and educational answer, Thank you for taking the time out your day to provide such answer. I will give it a shot now and see if my luck has changed somewhat over my lunch break! Thank you once again.

Comment: Your advise on adding ajaxVm. to both $set and $http worked instantly, I guess i spent 48 hours overlooking the basic fundamentals as i assumed it was something more complicated with being a new comer to the vue.js and js in general so i greatly appreciate that, The only issue i face Craig is have you ever come accross this error within the console:  TypeError: can't assign to properties of (new String("datas")): not an object. I have tried returning a full user object from laravel, i have tried returning a basic html string and a json object but fails when passing it to {{ datas }}

Comment: If you are returning json from laravel then just need to parse it first: `var response = JSON.parse(response.body);`